# Autofac register module with different lifecycle depends on the app (console or web)

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a classlib which is used by Console app and Web API. I am using Autofac module to register the dependencies as follows:

```
public class TenantAutofacModule : Autofac.Module
  {
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
      builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerTenant();
    }
  }
```

The lifecycle above `InstancePerTenant` works for Web API and does not work for Console app because the lifetime scope requires HTTP request.

I am wondering in the `TenantAutofacModule`, if there is a way to know who is the caller so that I could register the lifecycle either with `InstancePerTenant` or `InstancePerLifetimeScope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The lifecycle above InstancePerTenant works for Web API and does not work for Console app because the lifetime scope requires HTTP request.

`InstancePerTenant` doesn't require a HTTP request. It depends on your `ITenantIdentificationStrategy` implementation.

When you configure your container, you can choose a different implementation based on configuration

```
if(config.useConsole) {
    builder.RegisterType<ConsoleTenantResolverStrategy>()
           .As<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>()
           .SingleInstance();
} else {
    builder.RegisterType<WebTenantResolverStrategy>()
           .As<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>()
           .SingleInstance();
}
```

and to get your own `config` you can read [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index) which will give you the guidance for .net core